# How can i write this if statement on my template Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I would like to write something in the form of an entry to a particular tournament where the user after clicking on the "join" button is moved to a sheet where the user is asked to enter their name and choose which tournament they want to join. Is it possible to write a conditional instruction that checks if the name of a given tournament is equal to the name of the tournament that the user has chosen and using it to list the users assigned to the given tournament.

my views.py file

```
def content(request, pk):
    tournament = Tournament.objects.get(id=pk)
    users = TournamentUsers.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'ksm_app2/content.html', {'tournament': tournament, 'users': users})
```

my models.py file

```
class Tournament(models.Model):
    data = models.DateField(null=True)
    tournament_name = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True)
    tournament_creator = models.ForeignKey(Judges, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    tournament_info = models.TextField(max_length=10000)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tournament_name

class TournamentUsers(models.Model):
    user_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    user_last_name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    user_tournament = models.ForeignKey(Tournament, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_last_name + ' ' + self.user_first_name
```

```
    {% for user in users %}
        {% if user.user_tournament == tournament.tournament_name %}
            <p>{{ user.user_first_name }} {{ user.user_last_name }}</p>
        {% else %}
        <p>no one takes part in this tournament </p>
        {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
```

```
if u have any idea what i can do i will appreciate that.
```

Answer (score 2):

`.user_tournament` is a `Torunament`, so you check this with:

```
{% if user.user_tournament == tournament %}
    …
{% endif %}
```

but filtering in the template is *not* a good idea. It will make the server unresponsive if the number of `user`s keeps growing. You filter in the view with:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def content(request, pk):
    tournament = get_object_or_404(Tournament, pk=pk)
    users = TournamentUsers.objects.filter(user_tournament=tournament)
    return render(request, 'ksm_app2/content.html', {'tournament': tournament, 'users': users})
```

This will perform the filter on the database, which has index structures to do this efficiently. In that case you no longer filter in the template.

---

> **Note**: It is often better to use [**`get_object_or_404(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404),
> then to use [**`.get(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get) directly. In case the object does not exists,
> for example because the user altered the URL themselves, the `get_object_or_404(…)` will result in returning a *HTTP 404 Not Found* response, whereas using
> `.get(…)` will result in a *HTTP 500 Server Error*.